# Use MATLAB Classification Learner App .mat struct file to run prediction on Python app

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning

I trained a model using classification learner app. I could use the model within MATLAB. Is there any way that I can use the exported model in .mat format? I have tried using scipy but I couldn't find any related documentation about how I can proceed. The codes below are what I have tried up until now, and I can't be sure if it will work. I didn't show the codes in correct sequence since I commented out some of it after using it once such as `sio.whosmat`

1. I use `sio.whosmat` to find out the variable names in the `.mat` file
2. Then, I moved on to create 2 methods:

- `neural_net(self)` to retrieve the file path
- `import_neural_network_model(self, file_path, variable_name)` to load the file

From whosmat, I found two names `neural_net` and `__function_workspace__`

I am trying to find any related documentation on how to use the `neural_net` in the `.mat` struct file.

I didn't provide the full class that contains the methods below because it doesn't provide any useful information (and it is too long). My end goal is to input the data and run prediction using the existing model saved in `.mat` format as a `struct` file in MATLAB.

```py
import scipy.io as sio

var_info = sio.whosmat('trained_Neural_Net.mat')
variable_names = [info[0] for info in var_info]
for name in variable_names:
    print(name)

def neural_net(self):
    # Provide the file path and variable name
    file_path = 'trained_Neural_Net.mat'
    variable_name = 'neural_net'
    self.net = self.import_neural_network_model(file_path, variable_name)
    print(self.net)

def import_neural_network_model(self, file_path, variable_name):
    # Load the .mat file
    mat_contents = sio.loadmat(file_path)
    # Access the neural network model
    net = mat_contents[variable_name][0, 0]
    return net
```

Comment: How did you export the trained network from MATLAB? I'm not an expert on this but I don't think a NN can simply be saved from one framework and opened in another. Probably you want to do something like [export from MATLAB to ONNX](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/exportonnxnetwork.html) and then import the ONNX into your chosen NN framework in Python e.g. tensorflow, keras or whichever.

Comment: it appears as though the functions are actually methods of a class?   if so, please include the class for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)